# mySQL select query, get data from multiple tables with some logic

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables *users* and *activation_details*

Users table has these data. uid is primary key.

```
uid     |    user_name
______________________
 1     |    John Smith
 2     |    Mary Smith
 3     |    Nancy Smith
 4     |    Agent Smith
```

activation_details has these data

```
aid     |    is_activated   |  user_id
______________________________________
1      |         0         |     0
2      |         1         |     4
3      |         1         |     1
4      |         1         |     777
```

Please note that user id 777 is not in the users table.

I need the result in this format

```
aid     |    is_activated   |  user_name      
______________________________________________
1       |         0         |     0
2       |         1         |     Agent Smith
3       |         1         |     John Smith
4       |         1         |     777
```

If user id is present in the users table then username has to be displayed, else the user_id itself has to be displayed.

I tried some thing like this

```
SELECT aid, is_activated, user_id, users.user_name from activation_details, users WHERE users.uid = user_id
```

It gives this output, which is not useful.

```
aid     |    is_activated   |  user_name      | user_id
________________________________________________________ 
2       |         1         |     Agent Smith |     4 
3       |         1         |     John Smith  |     1
```

Is there anyway to get this output using mysql only, I can do it with multiple queries in PHP, but that is not what I am looking.

```
aid     |    is_activated   |  user_name
______________________________________
1       |         0         |     0
2       |         1         |     Agent Smith
3       |         1         |     John Smith
4       |         1         |     777
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use an outer join in combination with the `coalesce()` function (which returns the first non-null value in the selected columns) like this:

```
SELECT 
    a.aid, 
    a.is_activated, 
    a.user_id, 
    coalesce(b.user_name, a.user_id, 0) as User
from 
    activation_details a
        left outer join users b
            on a.user_id=b.uid
```

Edit: I added one more check for the `coalesce()` function which will return a `0` for the User in case both the `user_name` and `user_id` fields are null values.

Testing done in mysql:

```
mysql> select * from first
    -> ;
+------+-------+
| id   | title |
+------+-------+
|    1 | aaaa  |
|    2 | bbbb  |
|    3 | cccc  |
+------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select coalesce('a', id) from first
    -> ;
+-------------------+
| coalesce('a', id) |
+-------------------+
| a                 |
| a                 |
| a                 |
+-------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select coalesce('a', 1) from first;
+------------------+
| coalesce('a', 1) |
+------------------+
| a                |
| a                |
| a                |
+------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select coalesce(null, 1) from first;
+-------------------+
| coalesce(null, 1) |
+-------------------+
|                 1 |
|                 1 |
|                 1 |
+-------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: In MySQL, would you get a type conflict error if user_id is an integer?

Comment: @GordonLinoff No? An int is not null by default - unless it is a null value in which case it isn't an int?

Comment: . . this code "coalesce('a', 1)" fails in SQL Server.  I don't have MySQL on hand to test it.  However, it would be safer to cast user_id to a character type.

Comment: Perfect!! Worked like a charm. Thank you @Fluffeh

Comment: @GordonLinoff I added a few exmaples from mysql to show that it is safe (it would also work in Oracle btw).

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT t3.aid,t3.is_activated,
IF (t2.user_name IS NOT null, t2.user_name, t3.user_id)
FROM activation_details AS t3
LEFT JOIN users AS t2 ON t3.user_id = t2.uid;
```

i think this query will give the result

Comment: +1 @Sundar, I checked this, this is also working perfectly. Since I can accept only one answer I am accepted the first posted answer. +1 for this. Thanks a lot.